# English word for an art to convey as much information as possible using few words

Tags: word-request

While giving speeches one may be concise or not. I think there was a word for being very concise while conveying a lot of information. That's it - information condensed is as few words as possible. Is there a word for that in English?

Comment: Google **concise synonym** and take your choice. (But **concise** pretty much says it.)

Comment: There's a full phrase that's sometimes used: **economy of speech**.

Comment: @CanadianYankee this is closest one. I hoped there's a single word for this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [succinct](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/succinct)?

> marked by compact precise expression without wasted words

Comment: This word indeed is right, but I'm looking for a verb version of it. Like in the comment above with "economy of speech".